# How do I query for documents outside of given radius in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-query

How do I do a geospatial query for items *outside* a given radius? I don't want results sorted by distance, I just want all results outside of a given distance. Is the best/only option to use $minDistance and $near? I believe this only returns results ranked by distance. Or can I create a query using $geoWithin (or some other operator) that specifies results *outside* a given distance from a point?

Comment: You can use `$near`/`$nearSphere` with `minDistance`, or use `$geoWithin` with a 2-ring "donut" GeoJSON polygon with outside and inside rings approximating the max distance and min distance circles, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, that's the sort of answer I was looking for! Do you know how to create a circular GeoJSON polygon by any chance? I've seen some examples of square 'donuts' but not circular. I'll look around more online of course but thought I'd check in case you have a quick solution...